# Evaluation of volume integral for a pyramid

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\iiint_ E (x+y)dV$$ where $E$ is the pyramid with vertices $(1,1,1) , (0,0,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$.

After drawing the pyramid I am unsure how to dissect the volume into separate planes or how that would work. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the integral into two parts along the plane $z=y$

For the top integral you have
\begin{gather}
0\leq y\leq 1 \\
y\leq z\leq 1 \\
0\leq x \leq y
\end{gather}

$$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 \int_0^y(x+y) \, dx\, dz\, dy$$

For the bottom integral you have
\begin{gather}
0\leq y\leq 1\\
0\leq z\leq y\\
0\leq x \leq z\\
\end{gather}
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^y \int_0^z(x+y) \, dx\, dz\, dy$$

So your entire integral will be
$$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 \int_0^y(x+y) \, dx\, dz\, dy+\int_0^1 \int_0^y \int_0^z(x+y) \, dx\, dz\, dy$$